# Access data form entry

Tags: ms-access

I am relatively new to Access and have a question. I am creating a database for an assisted living community, regarding Dietary Restrictions. My question is: I would like to create a front end user form to add "New Menu Items". I have all tables normalized, but the issue is some "New Menu Items" may have zero restrictions, and some may have many. How do I do this?

Comment: Also, I would prefer a dropdown style menu to avoid data integrity issues.

Comment: Are you asking about how to create the user form or how to structure a database table to allow some menu items to have not dietary restrictions?

Comment: Looking for [subforms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b)?